# Progress Bar asp.net

Tags: c#, css, asp.net

My page is a web form with master page. All the code here is in `createUser.aspx`.

I have implement a progress bar in my for application. Since I have placed the script manager ,update panel tag, my form is only doing client side validation and its not running the code behind therefore no submission is being done

Here is the **CSS** for the progress bar:

```
  <style type="text/css">
    body
    {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        font-family: Arial;
    }
    .modal
    {
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 999;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        top: 0;
        background-color: Black;
        filter: alpha(opacity=60);
        opacity: 0.6;
        -moz-opacity: 0.8;
    }
    .center
    {
        z-index: 1000;
        margin: 300px auto;
        padding: 10px;
        width: 130px;
        background-color: White;
        border-radius: 10px;
        filter: alpha(opacity=100);
        opacity: 1;
        -moz-opacity: 1;
    }
    .center img
    {
        height: 128px;
        width: 128px;
    }
</style>
```

**Forms:**

```
 </asp:ScriptManager>
         <asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" runat="server" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="UpdatePanel1">
    <ProgressTemplate>
        <div class="modal">
            <div class="center">
                <img alt="" src="../images/loader.gif" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </ProgressTemplate>
</asp:UpdateProgress>
         <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <div class="form-group row justify-content-center mt-2">
            <asp:Label ID="lblUserType" runat="server" CssClass="col-md-2 col-form-label" Text="User"> </asp:Label>
            <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rdlUserType"
                OnSelectedIndexChanged="RadioButtonList1_SelectedIndexChanged"
                RepeatDirection="Horizontal"
                AutoPostBack="true"
                Width="100px"
                runat="server">
                <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="Type 1">Hello</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="Type 2">Hola</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:RadioButtonList>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row justify-content-center mt-2">
            <asp:Label ID="lblFname" CssClass="col-md-2 col-form-label" runat="server" Text="First Name"></asp:Label>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtFName" CssClass="form-control" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="revfname"
                    runat="server"
                    Display="Dynamic"
                    ForeColor="Red"
                    ControlToValidate="txtFName"
                    ValidationExpression="([A-Z][a-z]+)$"
                    SetFocusOnError="true"
                    ErrorMessage="Invalid Fname"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator
                    ID="rfvfname"
                    runat="server"
                    Display="Dynamic"
                    ForeColor="Red"
                    ControlToValidate="txtFName"
                    SetFocusOnError="true"
                    ErrorMessage="First Name is Mandatory"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row justify-content-center mt-2">
            <asp:Label ID="lblLName" CssClass="col-md-2 col-form-label" runat="server" Text="Last Name"></asp:Label>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtLName" CssClass="form-control" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="revLname"
                    runat="server"
                    Display="Dynamic"
                    ForeColor="Red"
                    ControlToValidate="txtLName"
                    ValidationExpression="([A-Z][a-z]+)$"
                    SetFocusOnError="true"
                    ErrorMessage="Invalid Fname"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator
                    ID="rfvLname"
                    runat="server"
                    Display="Dynamic"
                    ForeColor="Red"
                    ControlToValidate="txtLName"
                    SetFocusOnError="true"
                    ErrorMessage="Last Name is Mandatory"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row justify-content-center mt-2">
            <asp:Label ID="lblNic" CssClass="col-md-2 col-form-label" runat="server" Text="NIC"></asp:Label>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtNIC" CssClass="form-control" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator
                    ID="rfvNic"
                    runat="server"
                    Display="Dynamic"
                    ForeColor="Red"
                    ControlToValidate="txtNIC"
                    SetFocusOnError="true"
                    ErrorMessage="NIC is Mandatory"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                <asp:CustomValidator
                    ID="cvNic"
                    runat="server"
                    OnServerValidate="cvNic_ServerValidate"
                    ClientValidationFunction="CustomCompareValidator"
                    Display="Dynamic"
                    ForeColor="Red"
                    ControlToValidate="txtNIC"
                    SetFocusOnError="true"
                    ErrorMessage="Invalid NIC"></asp:CustomValidator>
                <asp:RegularExpressionValidator
                    ID="revNic"
                    runat="server"
                    ValidationExpression="^[a-zA-Z0-9\s]{14}$"
                    Display="Dynamic"
                    ForeColor="Red"
                    ControlToValidate="txtNIC"
                    SetFocusOnError="true"
                    ErrorMessage="Must contain 14 characters"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row justify-content-center mt-2">
            <asp:Label ID="lblPhone" CssClass="col-md-2 col-form-label" runat="server" Text="Contact Number"></asp:Label>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtPhone" CssClass="form-control" TextMode="Phone" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvMob" runat="server"
                    Display="Dynamic" ForeColor="Red"
                    ControlToValidate="txtPhone"
                    SetFocusOnError="true"
                    ErrorMessage="Contact number is Mandatory">
                </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row justify-content-center mt-2">
            <asp:Label ID="lblEmail" CssClass="col-md-2 col-form-label" runat="server" Text="Email"></asp:Label>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" CssClass="form-control" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvEmail" runat="server"
                    Display="Dynamic" ForeColor="Red"
                    ControlToValidate="txtEmail"
                    SetFocusOnError="true"
                    ErrorMessage="Email is Mandatory">
                </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="revEmail" runat="server"
                    ControlToValidate="txtEmail"
                    Display="Dynamic"
                    Text="Incorect Email"
                    SetFocusOnError="true"
                    ForeColor="Red"
                    ValidationExpression="^[a-z0-9][-a-z0-9._]+@([-a-z0-9]+[.])+[a-z]{2,5}$"
                    ErrorMessage="Incorrect Email"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
            </div>
        </div>

        <asp:Panel ID="pCol" Visible="false" runat="server">
            <div class="form-group row justify-content-center">

                <asp:Label runat="server"
                    CssClass="col-md-2 col-form-label">Colleges</asp:Label>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCol"
                        CssClass="form-control" runat="server">
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="revCol" runat="server"
                        ControlToValidate="ddlCol"
                        SetFocusOnError="true"
                        Display="Dynamic"
                        ForeColor="Red"
                        InitialValue="-1"
                        ErrorMessage="Colleges selection is Mandatory">

                    </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

                </div>

            </div>
        </asp:Panel>



        <div class="form-group row justify-content-center">
            <div class="offset-md-2 col-md-8">
                <asp:Button ID="btnCreate" runat="server" OnClick="btnCreate_Click" CausesValidation="true" CssClass="btn btn-success" Text="Create" />

            </div>

        </div>
```

**Code behind**

```
    protected void btnCreate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
}
```

The loader gif should appear with a block transparent background, but nothing is happening when I click on the submit button.
Normally the code behind should be an `ExecuteNonQuery()`, I want each time a query is run a loader appear.

I am doing it right?

Comment: But with that button click, then you DO HAVE a post-back and the whole web page travels up to server, runs code beind (5 seconds), and then when done, the web page now travels back down to client side, is replotted, and and code behind changes to the page are now displayed. You have to use a onclientClick event added to that button click event that displays the gif or whatever - you have to do this BEFORE the post-back occurs

Comment: Thank you for your answer, so your are saying to me to call the gif with an onClientClick?

Comment: yes - just have the little javascript routine display (un-hide) the animated gif.

Comment: Ok i will try it